# WordPress: Get attached image height and width

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I am grabbing attached images from a post and displaying them in an unordered list. It works great, except I need to now get the image `height` and `width`, in the same way that I got the `src`. This is my code:

**PHP**

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $iPostID );
foreach( $arrKeys as $key) {
    if( $key == $post_thumbnail_id )
        continue;
    $sImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($key);
    $sImgString = '<li><img src="' . $sImageUrl . '" alt="Thumbnail Image" /></li>';
    echo $sImgString;
}
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), it should return an array like `('/path/to/img.jpg',32,64)` where 32 is the width and 64 is the height... Read the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) for more information on the usage of this function.

Comment: @colindunnn You're lucky I've been working with wordpress this week ;)

Comment: You should add 'full' as the second parameter.

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki the person asking only wanted the thumbnail images, which is the default value of the second parameter. By default WordPress stores 4 image sizes: Thumbnail (150×150), Medium (300×300), Large (1024×1024), and Full.

Comment: @JKirchartz ah ok. Sorry. Misunderstanding. I thought he meant Featured image by thumbnail. I removed the downvote.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do something like this:

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 8 );
if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

@rgb_life Specify the 'full' parameter:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
wp_get_attachment_metadata( int $attachment_id, bool $unfiltered = false )
```

Result is an array where you can read width and height of attached image and all resized images which WordPress produces.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/