# How to capture width and height value of the featured images (Php)

Tags: php

In wordpress , The first image added to the subject is my featured image I added this code to function.php for this reason

```
// picture
function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
if(preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches)){
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
return $first_img;
}
else {
$first_img = get_template_directory_uri()."/images/default.jpg";
return $first_img;
}
}
//picture
```

and I Added following code to content.php

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()  ) {
          the_post_thumbnail('large');
        } else {
           echo '<img src="';
             echo catch_that_image();
             echo '" alt="'.get_the_title().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"/>';
        }   ?>
```

but There are no width and height values in my featured images (Google has warned me) , How can I get the width and height value of the featured image automatically?

Comment: try :  `style = "width:'.$width.' px; height:'.$height.' px;"`

Comment: width and height values are blank.

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WuYE-WSmUBQ/YFB2kyPvFlI/AAAAAAABFmc/nkcevmV0-0A6Hp-dFO6WzT904sAZuiPCgCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/width.png

Comment: Look, you have provided `$width` and `$height` variable in your question, How can I know that they are created and have some value or not? I have just corrected syntax for you to write `style` code properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641178/wordpress-get-attached-image-height-and-width

Comment: I edited my question, can you please check it again. Thank you.